# Extract contents of BLOB for all records in table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I currently have a table with over 150,000 records. Each record has a resume attached. My current project requires that I extract all resumes stored in the BLOB column into a folder on the file system.

I created a procedure based on an example I found that allows me to extract 1 record, but I can't figure out how to get it to loop through each record and extract all the files, once I remove the record identifier in the where clause the procedure fails with an error.

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WRITE_BLOB_TO_FILE", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

If anyone has any insight into though I'd really appreciate it.

Procedure I'm using below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Write_BLOB_To_File
AS
    v_lob_loc      BLOB;
    v_filename     VARCHAR2(255);
    v_buffer       RAW(32767);
    v_buffer_size  BINARY_INTEGER;
    v_amount       BINARY_INTEGER;
    v_offset       NUMBER(38) := 1;
    v_chunksize    INTEGER;
    v_out_file     UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

    BEGIN

        SELECT  cobrokes.subs.resume, cobrokes.subs.filename
        INTO    v_lob_loc, v_filename
        FROM    cobrokes.subs;

        v_chunksize := DBMS_LOB.GETCHUNKSIZE(v_lob_loc);

        IF (v_chunksize < 32767) THEN
            v_buffer_size := v_chunksize;
        ELSE
            v_buffer_size := 32767;
        END IF;

        v_amount := v_buffer_size;

        DBMS_LOB.OPEN(v_lob_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);

        v_out_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(
            location      => 'LOB_DIR', 
            filename      => v_filename, 
            open_mode     => 'wb',
            max_linesize  => 32767);

        WHILE v_amount >= v_buffer_size
        LOOP

          DBMS_LOB.READ(
              lob_loc    => v_lob_loc,
              amount     => v_amount,
              offset     => v_offset,
              buffer     => v_buffer);

          v_offset := v_offset + v_amount;

          UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW (
              file      => v_out_file,
              buffer    => v_buffer,
              autoflush => true);

          UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(file => v_out_file);

        END LOOP;

        UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(file => v_out_file);

        UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_out_file);

        DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(v_lob_loc);

    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it out and I'm leaving this here for anyone else that needs to accomplish this.

v_filename is the table's column that contains the file name of the file in the BLOB column and v_pkey is the primary key column in the table (I know most use ID for this column).

The output of this script saves the file with the file name in the pkey-filename structure, in my case, '102-some-file-name.docx', the reason for that is that we needed to bable to trace the document back to a record in the table and using the primary key was just the easiest way.

Hope this helps anyone else that needs to accomplish this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Write_BLOB_To_File
AS
   v_blob        BLOB;
   v_start       NUMBER             := 1;
   v_bytelen     NUMBER             := 32767;
   v_len         NUMBER;
   v_raw         RAW (32767);
   v_x           NUMBER;
   v_output      UTL_FILE.file_type;
   v_filename    VARCHAR2 (255);
   v_pkey    NUMBER;

BEGIN

   FOR i IN (SELECT DBMS_LOB.getlength (RESUME) v_len, FILENAME v_filename,
                    RESUME v_blob, PKEY v_pkey
               FROM COBROKES.SUBS)

   LOOP
      v_output := UTL_FILE.fopen ('LOB_DIR', i.v_pkey || '-' || i.v_filename || chr(0), 'wb', 32767);
      v_x := i.v_len;
      v_start := 1;
      v_bytelen := 32767;

      WHILE v_start < i.v_len AND v_bytelen > 0
      LOOP
         DBMS_LOB.READ (i.v_blob, v_bytelen, v_start, v_raw);
         UTL_FILE.put_raw (v_output, v_raw);
         UTL_FILE.fflush (v_output);
         v_start := v_start + v_bytelen;
         v_x := v_x - v_bytelen;

         IF v_x < 2000
         THEN
            v_bytelen := v_x;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;

      UTL_FILE.fclose (v_output);
   END LOOP;
END Write_BLOB_To_File;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

the error is simple-you can not fetch multiple row into a single object. try like this:-

```
    create or replace type blob_obj_handlr is table of BLOB;
    /
    create or replace type char_obj_handlr is table of varchar2(100);
    /
```

then execute the query like this

```
lv_b_resume :=blob_obj_handlr();
lv_v_filenm :=char_obj_handlr();

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('SELECT  cobrokes.subs.resume, cobrokes.subs.filename
        FROM    cobrokes.subs') BULK COLLECT into lv_b_resume,lv_v_filenm;
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't my strongest suit, how would I put that into my existing procedure?